# jquery sortElement: sort by numerical value of table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbvk5jLL/).

As you can see from the fiddle, the `total` column contains numbers that are currently sorted by text.

**Q:** How can I sort the `total` column by the numerical value?

```
var table = $('table');

    $('#facility_header, #city_header, #total')
        .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
        .each(function(){

            var th = $(this),
                thIndex = th.index(),
                inverse = false;

            th.click(function(){

                table.find('td').filter(function(){

                    return $(this).index() === thIndex;

                }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                        inverse ? -1 : 1
                        : inverse ? 1 : -1;

                }, function(){

                    // parentNode is the element we want to move
                    return this.parentNode; 

                });

                inverse = !inverse;

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the values before you compare them.

```
.sortElements(function(a, b){
    var sa = $.text([a]);
    var sb = $.text([b]);

    var ia = parseInt(sa);
    var ib = parseInt(sb);

    if (!isNaN(ia) && !isNaN(ib)) {
        return ia > ib ? (inverse ? -1 : 1) : (inverse ? 1 : -1);
    }

    return sa > sb ? (inverse ? -1 : 1) : (inverse ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Here's your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy00L2nw/).