# How can I order numerical columns with jQuery "sortElements" plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery script "sortElements" on my tables to sort their columns, but I noticed that the sorting in numerical columns doesn't work. The result of the sorting on them is something like "100 20 250 30". I don't understand how to solve this problem. Can you help me, please?

This is the "sortElements" script: https://j11y.io/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

This is the script that I'm using in my page:

```
var table = $('table');

$('table th')
.wrapInner('')
.each(function(){

    var th = $(this),
        thIndex = th.index(),
        inverse = false;

    th.click(function(){
        table.find('td').filter(function(){

            return $(this).index() === thIndex;

        }).sortElements(function(a, b){

            if( $.text([a]) == $.text([b]) )
                return 0;

            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                inverse ? -1 : 1
                : inverse ? 1 : -1;

        }, function(){

            // parentNode is the element we want to move
            return this.parentNode; 

        });

        inverse = !inverse;

    });

});
```

I FOUND A SOLUTION in this question: [jquery sortElement: sort by numerical value of table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717041/jquery-sortelement-sort-by-numerical-value-of-table-data?fbclid=IwAR00c8G94ll-lD_o70Hc4HPvJ4u-18AXCs7Yd1tiOVNTgyV95_CsMrnafME)

I didn't find it in my previous research.

Comment: You are doing a string comparison in your sort method. Try `intParse` on the values first.

Comment: I tried to use the `parseInt` but it's not working properly. First, when I click the first time on `th` nothing happen, when I click a second time the order change but... it only invert the order of the rows, and not sort numerically. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ks53dpvy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this question: [jquery sortElement: sort by numerical value of table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717041/jquery-sortelement-sort-by-numerical-value-of-table-data?fbclid=IwAR00c8G94ll-lD_o70Hc4HPvJ4u-18AXCs7Yd1tiOVNTgyV95_CsMrnafME)

I didn't find it in my previous research.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently comparing strings, and strings are compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which means that, when you're talking numbers as strings, they're arranged in the order of their digits' greater values, rather than their actual value. Essentially, sorting strings containing numbers gets all the `1`s first, and then if there are multiple numbers beginning with `1`, they look at the next digit, and so on. See these examples:

---

Demo 1:

```js
var numbers = ["2", "4", "3", "1"];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b);
console.log(numbers);
```

Here, the numbers are all single-digit, which means that they'll be arranged the correct way.

---

Demo 2:

```js
var numbers = ["1", "4", "7", "12"];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b);
console.log(numbers);
```

Here, we have the single-digit numbers `1`, `4` and `7`, which are sorted in the correct order, but we also have `12`, which is placed after `1`. This is because its first digit is a `1`, same as the `1` value, so the second digit of both numbers are compared. Since `2` is greater than the second digit of `1`, which is nothing, it's sorted after `1`.

---

Demo 3:

```js
var numbers = ["10", "1", "1.3", "5", "76", "6001"];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b);
console.log(numbers);
```

In this example, you can see that `1` is sorted first, as there's no second digit. The next item after `1` is `1.3`, and after that is `10`, which means that decimal points are "smaller" in lexicographical terms than `0`s.

---

What you should do is convert what you're comparing to numbers instead like so:

```
sortElements(function(a, b){
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    if( $.text([a]) == $.text([b]) )
        return 0;
    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ? inverse ? -1 : 1 : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried to use the `parseInt` but it's not working properly. First, when I click the first time on `th` nothing happen, when I click a second time the order change but... it only invert the order of the rows, and not sort numerically. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ks53dpvy/